# "Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory" in SFTP shell script

Tags: bash, sftp, expect

I have a Bash script on a RHEL 5 system I use to perform various secure file transfer operations between the server and many external systems. Normally the script works fine and uses expect to spawn an ftp session to do things like MGET and then rm'ing the files from the target server. However occasionally the script will error with the output "Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory", when attempting the file deletion after a successful MGET transfer.  At first glance, this error is straightforward and appears to indicate the file doesn't exist. But the script output shows the files exist and have been transferred normally:

```
SFTP protocol version 3
sftp> get /home/sistran/parchment/*.xml /nfs/ftp-banp/college_xml
Fetching /home/sistran/parchment/TQB10G4D.xml to /nfs/ftpbanp/college_xml/TQB10G4D.xml
Fetching /home/sistran/parchment/TQB1343C.xml to /nfs/ftp-banp/college_xml/TQB1343C.xml
```

Then my output shows the stat error:

```
sftp> quit
Result of error check: 617
!SFTP - Successful File Transfer Performed.
Connecting to abc.xyz.edu...

sftp> 
sftp> rm /home/sistran/parchment/TQB10G4D.xml
Couldn't stat remote file: No such file or directory
Removing /home/sistran/parchment/TQB10G4D.xml
Couldn't delete file: No such file or directory
sftp> quit
\r
```

This sometimes occurs a handful of times during a file transfer of many files in a batch operation. Unfortunately i cannot get my hands on the external server for troubleshooting. Below is a snippet of the script that performs the mget and rm:

```
 ....if [ "$F1" = "$ftp_success_string" ]; then
            if [ "$password_option" = "1" ]; then
 # ----- SFTP command here (password) -----
 /usr/bin/expect - << EOF
 spawn /usr/bin/sftp -oPort=$PORT $userid@$dest
 expect "assword: "
 send "${send_password}\r"
 expect "sftp> "
 send "rm $F2\r"
 expect "sftp> "
 send "bye \r"
 EOF
   err=$?
 else
    # ----- SFTP command here (public Key) -----
    echo "
    rm $F2
    quit
    "|sftp -oPort=$PORT -oPubkeyAuthentication=yes $userid@$dest 2>&1
  fi....
```

Help! I'm also open to not using expect, if there is a better method.

Comment: Don't know, but I wonder if it's a line-ending issue.  Try changing `rm $F2\r` to `rm $F2\n` and see if that does anything.  Maybe the `rm` command is seeing `/home/sistran/parchment/TQB10G4D.xml<CR>` (a four-character extension).  **By the way**, is the failure in the `expect` command path or in the `echo ... | sftp` path?

Comment: Consider modifying your removal expect script to list the contents of the remote directory just before deleting the files. That would establish whether the remote file is actually there or not.

Comment: Seems to me that the file could have been removed outside your scripting. Would `rm -f` instead of plain `rm` help you here?